# Impact of Repeatedly Creating and Deleting Hive Table

Tags: hadoop, hive, metastore

I have an use case which required around 200 hive parquet table.
I need to load these parquet table from flat text files. But we can not directly load parquet table from flat text file.
So I am using following approach

1. Created a temporary managed text table.
2. Loaded temp table with text data.
3. Created external parquet table.
4. Loaded parquet table with text table using select query.
5. Dropped text file for temporary text table (but keep table in metastore).

As this approach is keeping temporary metadata (for 200 tables) in metastore. So I have second approach is that I will drop temporary text table too along with text files from hdfs. And next time re-create temporary table and delete once parquet get created.

Now, as I need to follow above steps for all 200 tables for every 2 hours, So will creating and deleting tables from metastore impact anything in cluster during production?

Which approach can impact production, keeping temporary metadata in metastore, creating and deleting tables (metadata) from hive metastore?

Comment: *"we can not directly load parquet table from flat text file"* -- really? What makes you believe that? Can't you just create an EXTERNAL table to map your input text and INSERT INTO Parquet SELECT FROM ExtText?

Comment: Side note: I am now fully convinced that implementing the awkward LOAD instruction was a bad design choice from FB. It just makes amateurs believe that you must "load" data from HDFS to Hive -- although, actually, Hive stores all its data on HDFS anyway.

Comment: Thank you Samson for your response.

_"Can't you just create an EXTERNAL table to map your input text and INSERT INTO Parquet SELECT FROM ExtText?"_ -- This is the same thing I mentioned in the point 1 to 5. What I am trying to say that to load parquet table from text file you first need to create a text table then only you can load parquet table. So creating temporary text table every time is a good idea or not. Because as of now i don't see any alternative for this.
If can share any other idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Uh - what you mentioned in points 1 to 5 was about a *managed* TEXT table and an *external* Parquet table. But now you claim that you meant an *external* TEXT table (and probably a *managed* Parquet table), which makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Sorry about confusion, let me try in a different way.
If I create a parquet table (EXT or MANAGED), now to load it I need to have either data in parquet file or in some existing table (to that I can execute SELECT query). But I have data in text file, so I am creating a TEXT table (EXT or MANG) then running _"INSERT INTO TABLE AS SELECT"_ query.
I just trying to know is there any impact on Hive metastore due to creating TEXT table again for 200 times for every 2 hours.

Comment: An EXTERNAL table on your input TextFiles is the perfect fit for your need: you define it **once**, then an external process (Flume, Pig, MapReduce, Spark, file transfer...) creates/removes files at FS level and triggers the Hive job when things are stable. No need to drop and recreate the table all the time; it's the files that come and go.

Answer (score 0):

> Which approach can impact production, keeping temporary metadata in
>   metastore, creating and deleting tables (metadata) from hive
>   metastore?

No, there is no impact, the backend of the HiveMetastore should be able to handle 200 * n Changes per hour easily. If you're unsure start with 50 tables and monitor the backend DB performance.